# In Bootstrap, how do I make text stay within the parent div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to get the text associated with a link and a paragraph to stay within their parent div.

I set the outer boundary as col-sm-8 but the text links are overflowing, not sure what I'm doing wrong here but the code I'm currently using is directly below. FWIW, I've tried setting box-sizing as content-box on both the link and the paragraph with no luck:

```
<div class="col-sm-8"><!-- Begin Box -->
<div class="box">
<div class="box-thumb" onclick="window.open('/generationetfs')" style="cursor:pointer; background-image:url('/horizons/media/cssImages/ca/homepagetools/podcast.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<h2 class="box-title"><a class="box-link" href="/generationetfs" target="_blank">Generation ETFs Podcastasasasasasasasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas</a></h2>

<p>Welcome to Generation ETFs, a podcast series dedicated to the <strong>next generation of investingasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</strong></p>
</div>
<!-- End Box -->
```

The page in question is this, where you see the text overflowing the col-sm-8 boundary: http://kenticocms.fourthdimensioninc.com/homey

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to create a class like **.word-break{word-break: break-word;}** and define into **col-sm-*** div then inside div overflow words will break.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `overflow-wrap: break-word;`, it breaks long words and wraps them onto the next line. Example:

```
.class-name {overflow-wrap: break-word;]
```

> **Note:** In contrast to word-break, overflow-wrap will only create a
> break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without
> overflowing.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `word-break` property to keep the text from overflowing the parent's bounds.

```
.box-link {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

[Read more about `word-break`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)